# Is it possible to construct a boost::circular_buffer with a braced initialiser list?

Tags: c++, boost

The following fails to compile:

```
auto myCircularBuffer = boost::circular_buffer<int>{1,2,3,4};
```

with error:

```
`error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::circular_buffer<int>::circular_buffer(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`
```

Is there another mechanism for constructing the boost::circular_buffer with a braced initialiser list or perform another form of aggregate initialisation? Or do we have to push_back each element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html), circular_buffer doesn't have an initializer list overload. The only real alternative to pushing items one at a time would be the [`InputIterator, InputIterator` overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp9108320-bb).

Of course, you're free to make your own function that uses the `InputIterator, InputIterator` overload to let you use initializer lists:

```
template<typename T>
boost::circular_buffer<T> make_circular_buffer(const std::initializer_list<T>& init)
{
  return boost::circular_buffer<T>(init.begin(), init.end());
}

auto b = make_circular_buffer({1,2,3,4});
```